# C# Programmatic Mouse Movement/Clicks

Tags: c#, mouse, simulator

I want to create... basically a macro program. After you click **record**, it **keeps track of** all mouse (and maybe eventually keyboard) activity. Then you can **save** it, and **play** it, and the mouse should **move and click** in the **same spots** that it did when you were recording it.

I know how to grab global mouse events, but I *don't* know how to make mice move/click in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the win32 APIs for this

[`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`mouse_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx) will alow you to move/click the mouse.
look into [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) too for keyboard stuff, but its more complex.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData,
   UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: Note that `mouse_event` has been superseded by `SendInput`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a tool that already does this you could probably use [AutoItRecorder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autoit-recorder/). It will record [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) scripts that you can run.

Comment: Its not so much that I need the program, more I want to know how its done. But thanks anyways!